# vb.net Ms Word Table cell. How to insert a line break into a string?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, openxml

with OpenXML in Word (not Office interop), using regex.replace to replace a ###Field### with strings.  one ###Field3#### is in a table cell, and the replacement string needs a line break.  Noting seems to work to insert a newline into a string in a Word table cell.

VbCrLf..no

CrLf...no

chr(13) no

Environment.NewLine.... no

There has to be a way to break a string into lines in a table cell:

"12345" + ???? + "DDDDDD"  ---->

12335

DDDDD

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert a new Run into the same paragraph, after the Run that contains the Field.

Comment: What's a new Run?   Not familiar

Comment: @user743094 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686712.aspx#Mastering_Understanding